# D3.js: Bar chart show bars in wrong place

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm totally newbie with D3. This is a nightmare :S I don't know why my bar char shows the bars moved and not correctly located.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Edit single bar chart]

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in drawBar function. The correct code is:

```
  drawBars(canvas, data, scales) {
    canvas
      .selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "single-bar")
      .attr("x", d => OFFSET_LEFT + scales.xScale(d.name))
      .attr("width", scales.xScale.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", d => OFFSET_TOP + scales.yScale(d.value_y))
      .attr(
        "height",
        d => HEIGHT - OFFSET_BOTTOM - OFFSET_TOP - scales.yScale(d.value_y)
      );
  }
```